# Can Jenkins job-dsl plugin be used with Clearcase repository?

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, jenkins-job-dsl

If so, does anyone have a working example that he/she can post?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins talks to ClearCase mainly through:

- the [ClearCase Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin)
- or the [ClearCase UCM Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin)

There is however no known example of generating a job from the [Jenkins Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) for those two plugins.
You would need to create a [seed job](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial---Using-the-Jenkins-Job-DSL), and try to mimic the data provided by those ClearCase plugin from there, probably setting up and updating ClearCase views through a series of "shell" steps calling custom scripts:

```
steps {
    shell(initClearCaseViews)
}
```

In particular, there doesn't seem to be a "`clearcase`" `scm`, as there is one for git for instance:

```
scm {
    git("git://github.com/${project}.git", branchName)
}
```